# unable to type function in config express

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

hello i'm trying to type server config and i get this error.

also, if possible, please see if my typing is correct in other places, I'm just learning

This expression is not callable.\n  Type 'Iexpress' has no call signatures.
[image]

```
  interface Iexpress {
      static: (id: string) => string;
    }
    
    const expressQ: Iexpress = require("express");
    const bodyParser: {
      urlencoded(arg0: { extended: boolean }): string;
      json(): string;
      NodeRequire: (id: string) => string;
    } = require("body-parser");
    
    const path: {
      join: (__dirname: string, id2: string) => string;
      NodeRequire: (id: string) => string;
    } = require("path");
    
    const app: {
      get(
        r: string,
        r2: (req: string, res: { sendFile: (arg0: string) => string }) => string
      ): string;
      use: (id: string) => any;
      listen: (port: string | number, port2: () => void) => string;
    } = expressQ();
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      console.log("in development.");
    } else {
      console.log("in production.");
    }
    
    /* App Config */
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(expressQ.static(path.join(__dirname, "../dist")));
    
    /* Server Initialization */
    app.get("/", (req: string, res: { sendFile: (arg0: string) => string }) =>
      res.sendFile("index.html")
    );
    var port: string | number = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () =>
      console.log(
        `Server initialized on: http://localhost:${port} // ${new Date()}`
      )
    );
```

Comment: it has no call signatures because you assert `expressQ` as the interface `Iexpress` and that interface has no call signatures. Why not install `@types/express` and use the official types?

Comment: do all types in this file need to be typed via types/express?